# How to keep checking for new <li> elements in a <div>?

Tags: jquery, list, html-lists

I want to keep checking for new li elements  so that whenever there will be these new elements ,I would be getting new alerts?

**JS:**

```
$(function () {

    if ($('#div').find('<li></li>')) {
        alert('you just got new <li> elements');
    }

    // it is just an examplory function which                       
    // will keep looking for only  new <li> elements created by ol list

})();
```

Js fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/younis764/rWcKu/3/

Please help.

Comment: What is creating the new `li`s? Wouldn't it make sense to issue the alert when the `li` is created rather than having a separate function watching for it?

Comment: Try this for an IE8 compatible version http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MFkdq/2/

Comment: @Moob I want to set auto increase id of the li for new li's  created in the ol lists. if I will be able to get alerts for new li, then the rest is easy. Also please check my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/younis764/rWcKu/3/

Comment: I'm not seeing the whole picture here. Your fiddle shows an element being added by jquery. I'm guessing that this same chunk of html will get added multiple times and each one should have its own id. Sounds like it would be easiest to set an id each time you inject the new html.

Comment: @user1452376, Check my fiddle. it dynamically adds an Li to the DOM on click of the button. It works just like your code . How are you planning to add the li to the dom? on page load or any event like button click?

Comment: @MarsOne I only want to detect the li created by ol in textarea or editable div(but not by onclick event) like here http://jsfiddle.net/younis764/TZJph/ but I am getting multiple alerts with each li

Answer (score 3):

A function like this should help you

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event){
  var element = event.target;
  if (element.tagName == 'li') {
     alert("li added");    
  }
});
```

Check [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events)

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HY9Tc/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="container" style="background-color:#e0d0a0; width:300px; height:100px;"></div>   
<button onclick="AddLiToContainer ();">Add a li node to the container!</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 function AddLiToContainer() {
     var newLi = document.createElement("li");
     var textNode = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
     newLi.appendChild(textNode);
     if (newLi.addEventListener) {
         newLi.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', OnNodeInserted, false);
     }

     var container = document.getElementById("container");
     container.appendChild(newLi);
 }

 function OnNodeInserted(event) {
     var Li = event.target;
     alert("The text node '" + Li.innerHTML + "' has been added to an element.");
 }
```

Comment: but is this cross browser compatible? Does mutation events have little support in ie?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy  I tested it ,but its not working.I added jfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/younis764/rWcKu/3/   please check

Comment: @MarsOne Thank you so much.I want to detect the li only created by (not by onclick event) .In this new fiddle.on every  new one li,there is 3 times alert.Please review http://jsfiddle.net/younis764/TZJph/

Comment: @MarsOne Please click after the "Link text" to auto create the new li by ol here http://jsfiddle.net/younis764/TZJph/