# how to keep checking when there is an increase in the number of ol list?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I want an alert whenever there is an increase or decrease in the number of ol items. I am currently tracking this change (increase in numbers) with Counter variable.

```
<div id="txtarea" contenteditable="true">Some text</div>

 var counter=0;
var html = "<div class='steps '><ol ><li class='personid'  id='"+  
    counter++   +"' ><a href='url-here' >Link Text </a></li></ol><div>";
$('#textarea').html(html);
```

Comment: how is the new items added

Comment: What is the event that increase or decrease?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep checking for new <li> elements in a <div>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923102/how-to-keep-checking-for-new-li-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: Please post your code for insert or remove ol items

Comment: @Roopendra ,@Arun P Johny I have edited my question.Please review it.

Comment: We are asking to you , How you are triggering increase or decrease may be you are using any button or may be for any id click you triggering increase/decrease. So what you have written there? and also your id is mismatch in your pasted example. It should be `$('#txtarea').html(html);`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var old_content = $('#textarea').html();
setInterval(function(){
    if(old_content != $('#textarea').html()){
        alert('changed');
        old_content = $('#textarea').html();    
    }
},30);
```

Edit:Optimized version

```
var old_content = $('#textarea').html();
    setInterval(function(){
        var current_html = $('#textarea').html();
        if(old_content != current_html ){
            alert('changed');
            old_content =current_html;  
        }
    },30);
```

Comment: At least get the html only once inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not completely clear but as far as I understood the following can help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" class="myInput" /><input type="button" class="myBtn" value="submit" />
        <div class="myDiv">
            <ol>
                <li>Kundan</li>
                <li>Amit</li>
            </ol>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.myBtn').click(function () {
                $('.myDiv ol').append('<li>' + $('.myInput').val() + '</li>');
                alert( $('.myDiv ol li').length + ' row Inserted');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```